# Docusign Status Related list populating on Account instead of Contact object

Tags: salesforce, contacts, docusignapi, account

I have DocuSign and Salesforce connected, and am sending a DocuSign document from the standard Contact object.  However, the DocuSign Status and the DocuSign Recipient Status are populating on the Account object.  I have spoken to DocuSign Customer Support and they do not feel this is related to settings in DocuSign, but rather customization in Salesforce.  I need to figure out why it is routing the status' to the Account object.  Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

The DocuSign Status will populate on any object related to the record the envelope is sent from. You can get have it not populate at all on the Account object by removing the Update Fields to Account in dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c object in DocuSign Connect, but that defeats the purpose of having the DS Status related list on the Account object at all. Unfortunately, the DocuSign status cannot be related to a single object as those objects have related records in SFDC themselves. The DS Status related list is org wide showing records with any relation to the sent from object.

Comment: If that is the case, then why does the status fail to appear on the Contact object related list, where the document was originally sent from?